# Sharepoint PeoplePicker control not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, safari, sharepoint-2010, modal-dialog, peoplepicker

Good day

I have a asp page with people editor

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="Rater1" runat="server" Rows="1" Width="250" PlaceButtonsUnderEntityEditor="false" MultiSelect="false" />
```

When this page opened as modal dialog - it all right.
But when this page opened in new tab as full page - i can't select users in people picker dialog. When i press "Ok" button  - dioalog closes and nothing appears (people picker will be still empty). This problem appears in Chrome and Safari, but not in IE.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for me - in init.js you shall find and replace

```
if(!browseris.ie)if(window.frameElement!=null)window.fndlgClose=d
```

to

```
if(!browseris.ie)if(window.frameElement!=null||r)window.fndlgClose=d
```